# why wont tailwind css work on my react app?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I tried installing tailwind css through the guide on their site but it wont work.
i tried installing in both react and vite-react

the vite config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

the tailwind config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

also the package.json dependencies contain "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",

Comment: Do you load tailwind base, tailwind components, tailwind utilities in your css or scss as well?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation for Vite React](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite):

- Ensure you have `postcss` installed, by running the command:

  ```bash
  npm install -D postcss
  ```
- Ensure you have a `postcss.config.js` with Tailwind configured within it. It should look like:

  ```js
  export default {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
    },
  };
  ```
- Ensure you have a CSS file with the `@tailwind` directives:

  ```css
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
  ```
- Ensure the CSS with the `@tailwind` directives is `import`ed in one of your  "main" project JavaScript files:

  ```js
  import './path/to/file.css';
  ```
- Ensure the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the files that contain Tailwind class names.